# Azure Redis Cache stuck in Create

Tags: azure, caching, azure-gov

I created an Azure Redis Cache in Azure Government.  The deployment failed after almost a half hour - I have no idea why.  However, the ProvisioningState is stuck at Creating, which means I can't delete it.  Any ideas on how to delete it?

(I've done this in regular Azure several times, and everything works fine - I've only seen this in Azure Government.)

Comment: Seems like something worthy of a support ticket. Not sure there's a solution to be had here...

Comment: delete the resource group, if it won't help, the provisioning will fail after 2 hours and you can delete after

Comment: Took 15 min for Terraform to create cluster. But in dashboard still says "Creating".

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I wanted to make sure that people see this answer in case they have the same problem...

I tried to delete the entire resource group multiple times over the course of several hours, but it didn't work.  As David suggested, I ended up submitting a support ticket, and the MS support folks cleared up the problem overnight.  They said it was nothing that I did, but rather that "the Redis product group identified and mitigated an issue".